# Default show the title of marker in Google Map API

Tags: objective-c, google-maps, gmsmapview

I have added a marker as the following:

```
marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:desLocation];
marker.title = @"Title";
marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;
marker.snippet = @"Snippet";
[marker setMap:mapView];
```

It's OK!! But if i want to show the title and snippet of this marker, i have to tap on the marker. So, how could the GMSMapView show the marker's title and snippet automatically without tapper.

Tks for all help!!

Answer (score 9):

Just call:

```
[mapView setSelectedMarker:marker];
```

That should do what you want.

Comment: You can't show the title of multiple markers with this.